# Do we need closure under binary operation for infinite groups?

Tags: group-theory

We often say $(\Bbb Q\setminus \{0\},\times)$ is a group where $\Bbb Q$ is rational numbers, but in the group axioms which say we need closure of elements under group action between them.

Consider the limit for $e$
$$ e= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+ \frac{1}{n}\right)^n $$

Clearly raising an infinite repeat of the binary operation, it is not closed. So, is the correct statement for closure under binary operation for infinite group 'under finite applications'?

Comment: An infinite number of products is not a product.  (Even though that isn't what's going on here.)

Comment: How is that so? @Randall could you elaborate?

Comment: The closure property of $*$ is that $x*y \in A$ whenever $x, y \in A$.  This says nothing about $x_1 * x_2 * x_3 * \cdots$, whatever that means.

Comment: There is not an infinite number of terms being multiplied together in your limit.  Each term is a finite number of operations.  The **number** of terms you take the limit of is infinite, but that doesn't make it some sort of infinte product.

Comment: That isn't a group: $0$ has no inverse.

Comment: I have patched that @Shaun

Comment: I don't understand, could you rephrase your statement @Randall?

Comment: There is only an issue if you phrase the closure rule vaguely (the right formulation is "$x*y\in A$ whenever $x,y\in A$," as Randall observed, which is perfectly clear). There's no need to mention finite vs. infinite products.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a group $(G, \cdot)$, "closure of $G$ under the group law $\cdot$" solely means that $g \cdot h \in G$ for all $g, h \in G$. In other words, $\cdot$ is a function $G \times G \to G$.

Taking (topological/analytic) limits implies you have some topological structure (the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is the one used for the limit you mention). You could take the discrete topology, for example, but in a discrete space a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges if and only if $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is eventually constant. In terms of a sequence of products $\left(\prod_{k=0}^n{g_k}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ (with $(g_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ some sequence in $G$), this would entail that $g_n = 1$ (the group identity) for almost all $n$, devolving back down to a finitary product. (That said, your sequence isn't an infinite product, just a sequence of elements which happen to be products.)